# Нахождение кратчайшего пути в массиве

Tags: массивы, алгоритм

Есть двумерный массив допустим 7 на 7. В массиве есть n чисел идущих по порядку которые больше 0, например 1, 2, 3. Надо проложить пути на прямую от 1 к 2, от 2 к 3 и заполнить эти пути любыми числами не равными 0(в примере я использовал -1).
было:

```
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  3  0
0  0  2  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

стало:

```
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  0  0  0
0 -1  0  0  0  0  0
0 -1 -1  0  0  0  0
0  0 -1  0 -1  3  0
0  0  2 -1 -1  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

числа 1 2 3 можно оставить(как в примере), а можно и заменить на -1 или другое число не равное 0. Путь должен быть самый короткий и (ВАЖНО) идти напрямую(как луч) поэтому алгоритмы(волновой, Беллмана-Форда и тд) не подходят и не подойдут. Довольно долго бьюсь над этой задачей но ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: а вам какой язык то нужен для реализации? уточняйте

Comment: c# но можно и java

Comment: код написать я сам смогу, мне бы описание работы алгоритма.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.е. по сути, нужно провести отрезки.

Это можно сделать с помощью [алгоритма Брезенхема](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0) (или другого алгоритма растеризации прямых)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло